# Why find_each do not respect filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a rake task where everyday I should load 10_000 users and process, like this

```
uptime = Sys::Uptime.days
batch = 10_000

Person.limit(batch).offset(batch*uptime).find_each do |p|
  Namespace::UserWorker.perform_async(p.to_global_id)
end
```

turns out that debuggin, I realized that find_eachs seems to ignore my limits and offset, and loads more than 10000 users. What should I do? use `each` instead `find_each`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to group in batches and ActiveRecord has a helper for it:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches

```
batch_size = 1000
start = 0
Person.find_in_batches(batch_size:batch_size, start:start) do |p|
  Namespace::UserWorker.perform_async(p.to_global_id)
end
```

Comment: yes, but when I tried, it loaded all users. I need to limit the batch to 10_000 users, and I didn't found any option

Comment: If you just need to limit the size then put a limit on it as in: Person.limit(1000).find_in_batches ....

Comment: `Scoped order and limit are ignored, it's forced to be batch order and batch size` didn't worked

Answer (score 1):

`find_each` override `limit` and `offset` conditions for load only part/batch of data. So, in your case just don't specify own `limit` and `offset` conditions:

```
Person.find_each(batch_size: 10_000) do |p|
  Namespace::UserWorker.perform_async(p.to_global_id)
end
```

Comment: Actually, I need to import users from id 0 to 10_000 today, and tomorrow, 10_000 to 20_000 so this code may not work